# Calculating limit of a sum

Tags: calculus, limits

Helllo everyone,
I have to calculate a particular limit that contais a sum and I have no idea how to solve such problem. The task is to calculate this limit: 
$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\left(\frac n6\sum_{i=0}^\infty \left(\frac 56\right)^i\left(1-\left(\frac56\right)^i\right)^{n-1}\right) $$
I will be grateful for any hints or solutions.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: Just checking.  Is there any chance the sum should go from $0$ to $n$ rather than from $0$ to $\infty$?

Comment: I tried summing the expression inside, but it failed. The sum has to go from 0 to ∞

Comment: I managed to prove by comparison test, that the sum converges, but still I have no idea how to go further.

Comment: That's a really evil problem. If I understand things right, the limit does not exist but it "almost exists" in the sense that the difference between the upper and the lower limit is hardly noticeable. Where did you get it from?

Comment: The limit came out from solving another problem connected with probability.

Comment: The curve looks a lot like the distribution  curve of energy density by frequency when analyzing Black Body Radiation. I think some variations of the associated functions might shed some like. They are often of the form $\frac{x^p}{1+ce^{-kx}}$

Comment: Ah, OK. Then, as I said, the answer is that there is no limit but both the upper and the lower limits are very close to the number in the answers you got already. The questionable step is exactly the one when you pass from a Riemann sum to the integral.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I might have a start. I need to sort out error terms with my approximations.

I'm getting about $\frac{1}{6 \ln{6/5}}$ but my steps might be wrong.

Let:
$$\alpha=\frac{5}{6}$$
$$f(n)=\frac{1}{6}\frac{n}{n-1}(n-1)\sum_{i=0}^\infty\alpha^i(1-\alpha^i)^{n-1}$$

So:
$$f(n+1)=\frac{1}{6}\frac{n+1}{n}(n)\sum_{i=0}^\infty\alpha^i(1-\alpha^i)^{n}$$

Here's a questionable step.

Does this hold?: 
$$(1-\alpha^i)^n=(1-n\alpha^i/n)^n=e^{-n\alpha^i}$$

Then for large n:

$$f(n+1)=\frac{1}{6}\sum_{i=0}^\infty \ n\alpha^ie^{-n\alpha^i}$$

Then we approximate the sum with an integral substituting x for i.

$$f(n+1)\approx\frac{1}{6}\int_{0}^\infty na^xe^{-na^x}dx$$

Let $u=n\alpha^x$

Then: 
$du=n \ln{\alpha} \alpha^x dx$

So :
$$f(n+1)\approx \frac{1}{6}\int_{n}^0 \frac{1}{\ln{\alpha}}e^{-u}du$$

Integrating:

$$f(n+1)\approx \frac{1}{6\ln{\alpha}}=\frac{1}{6\ln{\alpha}}(-e^{-u})|_n^0=\frac{-1+e^{-n}}{6\ln{\alpha}}$$

Looks accurate:
[image]

Comment: This agrees to many decimals with my numeric result.

Answer (score 3):

Some playing around, but not an answer.  If we set $x=\left(\frac 56\right)^i$ we can find the largest term in the sum by differentiating $x(1-x)^{n-1}$ and setting to zero.  It turns out the maximum is at $x=\frac 1n$ or $i=\frac {\log n}{\log 1.2}$.  The value of the maximum term is about $\frac 1{ne}$.  If we plot the terms of the sum they are sharply peaked around the maximum and the width appears indpendent of $n$.  The figure below is for $n=10000$, where the peak is at $i=50$ or $51$. The horizontal axis is $i$ and the vertical axis is the term in the sum 
[image]
I also plotted $n=10, 100, 1000$ and the width and shape of the peak do not seem to change.  I wrote a Python program to sum the series out to $i=100000$, summing from the top down so we don't lose significance adding the tiny terms.  The result was consistent to better than ten figures for all the $n$ I tried from $10$ to $10^6$ at $0.91413582462$

Comment: Thank for your effort. The result seems to be quite interesting for me

Comment: Your curve is very interesting. I graphed it and found an invariance in n. Changing n just moves the curve side to side. If we let n=1 in the original expression we get a geometric series in a starting with 1. Interesting. Upon integration it takes on a ln a in the denominator. which is looking to be part of the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Also not an answer, but you can replace the infinite sum by a finite one as shown below.  A blunder in my earlier attempt to carry out this calculation was responsible for my erroneous assertion that the sum diverged as $\ n\rightarrow\infty\ $.
\begin{eqnarray}
\sum_{i=0}^\infty \left(\frac 56\right)^i\left(1-\left(\frac56\right)^i\right)^{n-1} &=&
\sum_\limits{i=0}^\infty\left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^i\sum_\limits{j=0}^{n-1}{n-1\choose j}\left(-1\right)^j\left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^{ij}\\
&=&\sum_\limits{j=0}^{n-1}\left(-1\right)^j{n-1\choose j}\sum_\limits{i=0}^\infty\left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^{i\left(j+1\right)}\\
&=& \sum_\limits{j=0}^{n-1}\frac{\left(-1\right)^j{n-1\choose j}}{1-\left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^{j+1}}\\
\end{eqnarray}

Comment: For $n=11,$ [Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+(5%2F6)%5En(1-(5%2F6)%5En)%5E10+from+0+to+infinity) says the sum converges and gives a value of about $0.49862$.  For $n=101$ Alpha said the sum converged by the limit test but ran out of time before giving a value.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. My assertion that it diverges resulted from an error in my earlier attempt to carry out the calculation I've now given above.

Comment: Oh thanks, that's a good one. I didn't think it is possible